# How can I use JSManagedValue to avoid a reference cycle without the JSValue getting released?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, javascriptcore

I'm running into issues while trying to use JSManagedValue. From my understanding based on [Session 615 at WWDC 2013](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc/videos/), when you want to have a reference from Objective-C to Javascript and vice-versa, you'll need to use JSManagedValue instead of just storing the JSValue in Objective-C to avoid a reference cycle.

Here's a stripped-down version of what I'm attempting to do. I have a ViewController which needs a reference to a Javascript object, and that Javascript object needs to be able to call a method on the ViewController. The ViewController has a UILabel which displays a count, and has two UIButtons, 'Add' which increments the count, and 'Reset', which creates and replaces the current view controller with a new ViewController (basically just so I can verify the old ViewController gets cleaned up properly while I'm testing this).

In `viewDidLoad`, the ViewController calls `updateLabel` and is able to correctly fetch the count from the Javascript object. However, after that run loop finishes, Instruments is showing that the JSValue is getting released. The ViewController still exists, as does its JSManagedValue, so I thought that should prevent the JSValue from being garbage collected, but `_managedValue.value` now returns nil.

If I just store the JSValue instead of using JSManagedValue, it all works visually, but there is a reference cycle between the ViewController and the JSValue, as expected, and Instruments confirms that the ViewControllers are never released.

**Javascript Code:**

```js
(function() {
  var _count = 1;
  var _view;
  return {
    add: function() {
      _count++;
      _view.updateLabel();
    },
    count: function() {
      return _count;
    },
    setView: function(view) {
      _view = view;
    }
  };
})()
```

**CAViewController.h**

```objc
@protocol CAViewExports <JSExport>
- (void)updateLabel;
@end

@interface CAViewController : UIViewController<CAViewExports>
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *countLabel;
@end
```

**CAViewController.m**

```objc
@interface CAViewController () {
    JSManagedValue *_managedValue;
}
@end

@implementation CAViewController

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        JSContext *context = [[JSContext alloc] init];

        JSValue *value = [context evaluateScript:@"...JS Code Shown Above..."];
        [value[@"setView"] callWithArguments:@[self]];

        _managedValue = [JSManagedValue managedValueWithValue:value];
        [context.virtualMachine addManagedReference:_managedValue withOwner:self];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self updateLabel];
}

- (void)updateLabel {
    JSValue *countFunc = _managedValue.value[@"count"];
    JSValue *count = [countFunc callWithArguments:@[]];
    self.countLabel.text = [count toString];
}

- (IBAction)add:(id)sender {
    JSValue *addFunc = _managedValue.value[@"add"];
    [addFunc callWithArguments:@[]];
}

- (IBAction)reset:(id)sender {
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    CAAppDelegate *appDelegate = app.delegate;
    CAViewController *vc = [[CAViewController alloc] init];
    appDelegate.window.rootViewController = vc;
}
```

What is the correct way to handle this setup so that the JSValue is retained throughout the lifetime of the ViewController but no reference cycles are created so that the ViewController can be cleaned up?

Answer (score 2):

I was confused by this as well. After reading the JavaScriptCore headers as well as the ColorMyWords sample project, it appears that for a managed value to keep its value alive, the owner must be visible to JavaScript (i.e., assigned to a value in the context). You can see this described in the `-loadColorsPlugin` method of AppDelegate.m in the ColorMyWords project.

Comment: I think this is correct. I'm forced to read the source code out of the video for session 615 to confirm this though: It would be nice if the sample project were still available.

Comment: Sample code is currently here: https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action?name=WWDC%202013

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, but have you tried adding the JSContext *context and JSValue *value properties to your class's private interface?

My hunch is that you are creating the JSContext *context in your initialization, but not retaining it at all, so it looks like your entire JSContext might be collected up through ARC as well as your JSValue *value at some unexpected point. But it's tricky because you are referencing it through _managedValue...

I'm not 100% certain about this, but my guess is that you shouldn't need a managedValue at all. You're not passing a JSValue in from Javascript during your call to `-(void)updateLabel` which is the scenario the speaker at the WWDC described would be problematic. What you ought to do instead, since your code is referencing the JSValue *value from your JSContext throughout, is to add both to your interface in your `.m`.

I also notice that you're reloading the count and add functions into JSValues every time you run the ObjC methods that need them. You can just keep them as part of the class so they are only loaded once.

So instead of:

```
@interface CAViewController () {
    JSManagedValue *_managedValue;
}
@end
```

It should be something like:

```
@interface CAViewController ()
@property JSContext *context;
@property JSValue *value;
@property JSValue *countFunc;
@property JSValue *addFunc;
@end
```

And the rest of your class should look like:

```
@implementation CAViewController

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _context = [[JSContext alloc] init];

        _value = [_context evaluateScript:@"...JS Code Shown Above..."];
        [_value[@"setView"] callWithArguments:@[self]];

        _addFunc = _value[@"add"];
        _countFunc = _value[@"count"];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [self updateLabel];
}

- (void)updateLabel {
    JSValue *count = [self.countFunc callWithArguments:@[]];
    self.countLabel.text = [count toString];
}

- (IBAction)add:(id)sender {
    [self.addFunc callWithArguments:@[]];
}

- (IBAction)reset:(id)sender {
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    CAAppDelegate *appDelegate = app.delegate;
    CAViewController *vc = [[CAViewController alloc] init];
    appDelegate.window.rootViewController = vc;
}
```

Since you mentioned you want to clear it all by just killing the ViewController, the JSContext and the JSValue will no longer have a reference because they too will go along with the ViewController (in theory? :P).

Hope this helps. I'm new to Objective C (let alone the JavaScripCore framework) so I could actually be way off!